# Как сделать вертикальную линию между словами?

Tags: html, css

Изучил основы html и css, начал практиковаться в вёрстке макетов. Сверстал один макет, начал второй, но появилась сложность с меню в шапке. Не знаю как сделать такую вертикальную линию между слов. Спасибо за помощь![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

да куча вариантов, как вы это можете сделать

**вариант 1:**

```css
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    
    padding: 5px 10px;
    
    font-size: 20px;
    
    border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.text:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class = 'text'>текст 1</div>
    <div class = 'text'>текст 2</div>
</div>
```

**вариант 2:**

```css
.text {
    display: inline;
    
    padding: 0px 10px;
    
    font-size: 20px;
}

.vr {
    display: inline;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'text'>текст 1</div>
<div class = 'vr'></div>
<div class = 'text'>текст 2</div>
```